# Change timestamp to select from previous week starting now

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a query in Bigquery that selects all of the data entires made within the last week. However, I just noticed that the code I have is selecting the data from the previous week (Sunday to Sunday) and not the immediate week starting from whenever I run the query. How can I change this query to accomplish that. Thanks for the help!

```
#standardsql
SELECT count(distinct DeviceID)
FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.test2`
Where PeripheralType = 5
AND EXTRACT(WEEK FROM createdAt) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 1 
AND serial != 'null'
```

I tried to run the query below but this would not select any data entries that were made today.

```
AND EXTRACT(day FROM createdAt) = EXTRACT(day FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 7
```

Comment: for current day - do you mean to select from last Sunday till Today?

Comment: No to just select the previous 7 days. I will add what I attempted to my question that didnt work.

Comment: so if today is Wed - so yo want from last wed till yesterday (Tue)? assuming the current day is not completed yet

Comment: No I would prefer to get all entries made before the query is run. I have a script that updates the table right before these queries are ran. The entries are coming from my real-time firebase database.

Comment: so! from last Wed till today (Wed)? can you be specific  please :o)

Comment: yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that createdAt is a timestamp - you should use:

```sql
WHERE DATE(createdAt) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

So, your example would be like below

```sql
#standardsql
SELECT count(distinct DeviceID)
FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.test2`
Where PeripheralType = 5
AND DATE(createdAt) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()    
AND serial != 'null'
```